# La salida de datos de los vectores de caracteres se repite en lenguaje C ¿cómo puedo solucionar?

Tags: c, vectores

Tengo un incoveniente al momento de mostrar los datos en pantalla de los vectores. Además, necesito solo digitar el caracter "*" asterisco para que el programa finalice y muestre los datos introducidos.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRLEN 256`

int main(void) {

    char a[MAX_STRLEN];
    char b[MAX_STRLEN];
    char c[MAX_STRLEN];
    int i;
    int n;
    char resp[MAX_STRLEN];
    char resp2[MAX_STRLEN];
    char * v[MAX_STRLEN];
    char * z[MAX_STRLEN];

    n = 0;
    do {
        printf("Caracter 1: \n");
        scanf("%s",a);
        printf("Caracter 2: \n");
        scanf("%s",b);
        if (strcmp(a,b)<=0) {
            
            
                strcpy(resp2, "Verdadero");
            
        } else {
            if (strcmp(a,b)>0) {
                
                strcpy(resp2, "Falso");
                
            }
        }
        n = n+1;
        v[n-1] = a;
        z[n-1] = b;
    
    
        printf("Desea continuar: Digite s y para salir digite * \n");
        scanf("%s",resp);
        /* resp="*" //o n=max */
    } while (strcmp(resp,"*")!=0);
    
    /* Escribir "Elementos son: " */
    printf("CARACTER 1 CARACTER 2 RESULTADO\n");
    /* Escribir v[n],"           ", z[n],"        ",  res2 */
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        printf("%s           %s        %s\n",v[i-1],z[i-1],resp2);
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si solo quieres un carácter usa **%c** en lugar de **%s**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas declaraciones:

```
char * v[MAX_STRLEN];
char * z[MAX_STRLEN];
```

No son para crear punteros que apunten a cadenas de texto de longitud `MAX_STRLEN`, sino que aquí estás creando un puntero con capacidad para apuntar a `MAX_STRLEN` arrays.
Dicho esto, las asignaciones:

```
    v[n-1] = a;
    z[n-1] = b;
```

No están copiando el contenido de `a` en `v[n-1]`, sino que estás copiando **la dirección de memoria** de `a` en la posición `v[n-1]` del puntero. Dado que `a` es una variable local a `main`, lo que sucede es que **todas las posiciones** de `v` almacenarán la misma dirección de memoria, y lo mismo sucede en `z`.

La solución pasa por crear un array de cadenas de caracteres en vez de un array de punteros ... y copiar las cadenas:

```
#define MAX_ARRAYS 200

char v[MAX_ARRAYS][MAX_STRLEN];

strcpy(v[n-1], a);
```

Y lo mismo para `z`